# Renaming Bunch of Files using MSBuild

Tags: msbuild

I need to rename bunch of Files by using MSBuild. Can anyone suggest any idea ?

This is my requirement..

1. Test1_20140415_Next.txt
2. Test2_20140415_Next.txt
3. Test3_20140415_Next.txt

Above files should be renamed as

1. Test1_20140416_Next.txt
2. Test2_20140416_Next.txt
3. Test3_20140416_Next.txt

Just replacing the date.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

This works.  I am importing 2 libraries.

I actually get today's date...not a hard coded one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project  ToolsVersion="4.0"  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="AllTargetsWrapped">

    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\ExtensionPack\4.0\MSBuild.ExtensionPack.tasks"/>
    <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets" />

    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- Always declare some kind of "base directory" and then work off of that in the majority of cases  -->
        <WorkingCheckout>.</WorkingCheckout>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="AllTargetsWrapped">
        <CallTarget Targets="SetTodayProperty" />
        <CallTarget Targets="CopyWithNewNameThenDeleteFiles" />
    </Target>   

    <Target Name="SetTodayProperty">
        <Time Format="yyyyMMdd">
            <Output TaskParameter="FormattedTime" PropertyName="UniqueDateStampTag" />
        </Time>
    </Target>


    <Target Name="CopyWithNewNameThenDeleteFiles">
        <ItemGroup>
            <AllFiles Include="$(WorkingCheckout)\MySourceFolder\**\*.*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <MSBuild.Community.Tasks.RegexMatch Expression="20140415_Next\.txt$" Input="%(AllFiles.FullPath)">
            <Output TaskParameter="Output" ItemName="MatchedFiles" />
        </MSBuild.Community.Tasks.RegexMatch>

        <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.TextString TaskAction="Replace" NewValue="$(UniqueDateStampTag)" OldString="%(MatchedFiles.FullPath)" OldValue="20140415">
            <Output TaskParameter="NewString" ItemName="NewFiles" />
        </MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Framework.TextString>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(MatchedFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(NewFiles)" />
        <Delete Files="@(MatchedFiles)" />
    </Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: If you found the answer, etiquette is to mark the answer as "answered" so it does not show up on Stack.O.F "not answered" queries.  And if (any) answer was helpful, to click the up-arrow on the response.